# Consulta MYSQL lenta, ao buscar pela data

Tags: mysql, select, data, where

Estou fazendo uma busca por data no mysql, mas fica muito lenta (mais de meio segundo).

Tem alguma forma de otimizar essa busca para ficar mais rápida?

Ex: de consulta:

```
SELECT dt.data,count(d.id) AS downloads, DATE_FORMAT(d.data, '%d/%m/%Y') as dataformat, DATE_FORMAT(d.data, '%d/%m') as dia, DATE_FORMAT(d.data, '%a') as semana FROM sig_datas dt
LEFT JOIN sig_downloads_historicodownload d ON DATE_FORMAT(dt.data, '%d/%m/%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(d.data, '%d/%m/%Y')
WHERE dt.data >= '2020-05-22'
AND dt.data <= '2020-05-25'
GROUP BY dataformat
ORDER BY dt.data ASC
```

Comment: Qual o motivo de você formatar as datas no critério de junção? Idem no GROUP BY?

Comment: para poder mostrar o numero total de downloads por dia

Comment: Mas seu campo `dt.data` já não é do tipo `date`? Ou é do tipo `datetime` ou `timestamp`?